# Почему не правильно работает функция?

Tags: javascript, функции, время

Почему к примеру если указать "17:00","19:00" выведет правильно 7200000ms - то есть до oldtime 2ч.

А вот если указать "22:00","00:00" выведет 79200000ms хотя до "00:00" 7200000ms

В чём проблема?

```
var nowtime = "17:00"
var oldtime = "19:00"

function Ms(str){
   const [h, m] = str.split(':').map(v => +v)
   const d = new Date();
   d.setHours(h);
   d.setMinutes(m);
   d.setSeconds(0);
   return d.getTime();
}

Ms(nowtime)-Ms(oldtime);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы указываете 00:00 он не знает, что это следующий день и считает, что между 22:00 и 00:00 не 2 часа, а 22 часа. Чтобы указать что это следующий день прибавляйте к дате 24 * k, где k - это количество дней после текущего. Ну или просто указывайте 24 вместо 00.

```
var nowtime = "22:00"
var oldtime = "24:00"

function Ms(str){
    const [h, m] = str.split(':').map(v => +v)
    const d = new Date();
    d.setHours(h);
    d.setMinutes(m);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    return d.getTime();
}

console.log(Ms(nowtime)-Ms(oldtime));
```

На выходе дает: 7200000

```
var nowtime = "00:00"
var oldtime = "22:00"

function Ms(str, days = 0){
    const [h, m] = str.split(':').map(v => +v)
    const d = new Date();
    d.setHours(days * 24 + h);
    d.setMinutes(m);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    return d.getTime();
 }


console.log(Ms(nowtime, 1)-Ms(oldtime));
```

Дает такой же результат.